# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Splitfn", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I've used the following split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Splitfn(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
 as       
begin       
declare @idx int       
declare @slice varchar(8000)       
  
select @idx = 1       
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       
  
while @idx!= 0       
begin       
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
    if @idx!=0       
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
    else       
        set @slice = @String       
      
    if(len(@slice)>0)  
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
    if len(@String) = 0 break       
end   
return      

end
```

and i used this function in a query and it was executed

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Employees_Delete] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Id varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

 if exists( select Emp_Id from Employee where Emp_Id=dbo.Splitfn(@Id,','))
begin
    update Employee set Is_Deleted=1 where Emp_Id=dbo.Splitfn(@Id,',')
    select 'deleted' as message
end 
END
```

but when i excute my store procedure giving values say (1,2) i got the error

```
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined 
function or aggregate "dbo.Splitfn", or the name is ambiguous.
```

I've checked my tablevalued functions the function 'splitfn' was there but I don't know what is going wrong? Any suggestions..

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It's a table-valued function, but you're using it as a scalar function.

Try:

```
where Emp_Id IN (SELECT i.items FROM dbo.Splitfn(@Id,',') AS i)
```

But... also consider changing your function into an inline TVF, as it'll perform better.

Comment: @Rob it worked for me.. How to change it into an inline TVF.. Plz guide me

Comment: There are lots of examples around. Here's one: http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/splitting-a-delimited-string-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was having the same problem and I couldn't figure out for the life of me what was going on. You saved me a huge headache.

Comment: For anyone who's looking for the site @RobFarley linked to: http://web.archive.org/web/20110319054025/http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/splitting-a-delimited-string-part-1/

Answer (score 13):

You need to treat a table valued udf like a table, eg JOIN it

```
select Emp_Id 
from Employee E JOIN dbo.Splitfn(@Id,',') CSV ON E.Emp_Id = CSV.items
```

Answer (score 13):

Works

```
select * from [dbo].[SplitString]('1,2',',')
```

Doesn't Work

```
select [dbo].[SplitString]('1,2',',')
```

1. **`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SplitString]('1,2',',')`**: This query asks the database to give us all the pieces (like rows in a table) that come from using the `[dbo].[SplitString]` tool with the input '1,2' and ',' (comma) as instructions. It works because we're using the tool the right way, expecting a bunch of results.
2. **`SELECT [dbo].[SplitString]('1,2',',')`**: This query also uses the `[dbo].[SplitString]` tool, but here, we're asking it for just one piece, not many. However, if the tool is built to give us many pieces (like a list), it gets confused and says, "I can't give you just one, I have a whole list!" So, it doesn't work because we're using the tool the wrong way for what we want.

Answer (score 6):

Since people will be coming from Google, make sure you're in the right database.

Running SQL in the 'master' database will often return this error.

Comment: For those struggling with replication errors. This should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

```
Database -> Tables -> Functions -> Scalar Valued Functions - dbo.funcName 
rightClick => Properties -> Search UserRoles + Add user access
```

[image]