# Within the Stored Procedure pass the array into a table valued Function for parsing

Tags: t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or aggregate “dbo.Splitfn”, or the name is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091830/cannot-find-either-column-dbo-or-the-user-defined-function-or-aggregate-dbo-s)

--function that parses an array based on any delimiter

```
CREATE FUNCTION valuedfunction
(
    @string VARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE(
    data VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string)

    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN
        IF @end = 0 
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (data) 
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))
        SET @start = @end + 1
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    END

    RETURN

END
```

--stored procedure that supports a comma separated value list of employee IDs.  I use the function ---(valuedfunction) to get the employee data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE commaseparated  
@keyList varchar(40) 
AS 
SELECT Title, Birthdate 
FROM HumanResources.Employee WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE EmployeeID IN (dbo.valuedfunction(@keyList))
```

--This is the problem:  I am getting errors below:  What am I missing
    exec commaseparated '10,11,12,13';

--ERROR MESSAGE:
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure commaseparated, Line 4
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.valuedfunction", or the name is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
WHERE EmployeeID IN (select data  from dbo.valuedfunction(@keyList))
```